# Goutte, how to send body post

Tags: php, guzzle, goutte

Hi using guzzle I can send a body post like this:

```
 $client = new GuzzleClient(['timeout' => 60, 'verify' => false, 'headers' => [
   'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 ]]);

 $response = $client->request('POST', $url, ['body' => $body]);
 print_r($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

But on goutte ain't working, anyone knows how?

Comment: what is `$body` ?

Comment: Can you even send post requests with Goutte? It's a *scraping* library, not a HTTP wrapper. That said, you can easily inject your own Guzzle client so you can do whatever you want: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte#usage

Comment: $body is a long post

Comment: @C2486 Also you can inject your guzzle to goutte but only the parameters, but you need to do a request option and then give the body post, I don't know how pass that parameter.

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried so far? Where **exactly** are you stuck?

Answer (score 4):

Simply do this, pass your parameters as third parameter.

```
$crawler = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.symfony.com/blog/', $params);
```